# fread does not drop whitespace before column names?

Tags: r, data.table

So I am using the `fread` function to read a .csv file. Some of the headers have spaces before them, like headers B, C and E below:

`headerA, headerB, headerC,headerD, headerE`

I used a selective `fread` function to read in only `headerB` and `headerC`. After that, referencing either of the headers gives me this issue:

`> foo[,"headerB", with=FALSE]
NULL`

And if I add a space in front of the header name, it works:

`> foo[," headerB", with=FALSE]
(data shows correctly)`

which means that `fread` is parsing the space in front of the header name as part of the colNames string. This makes it difficult to use syntax such as `foo$headerB`, etc later.

Is there anyway to get around this issue, short of using `setname(foo, " headerB", "headerB")` on the offending columns?

The actual `fread` command used was:
`foo <- fread("data.csv", colClasses=list(NULL=c(1:5,8:14), "POSIXct"=c(5,6))  )`
. I left `sep` as `auto` originally, but using `sep=", "` did not help.

Thanks.

Comment: Try trimming the whitespace from names(foo) with `stringr::str_trim` command.

Comment: Not clear how `fread` could guess what's on purpose and what's not. Easy to fix after: `setnames(foo, sub('^ *', '', names(foo)))`

Comment: @eddi, i was wondering if fread would drop any non-relevant whitespace as some programs do. Like you said, an easy fix, and you have a solution that is more elegant than mine. If you'd like to post your solution as an answer i'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data.table` allows you to have arbitrary column names, and because of that it can't really know when your spaces are intentional and when they are there by mistake.

Since you yourself do have the knowledge of what shouldn't be there, you can easily fix it:

```
setnames(foo, sub('^ *', '', names(foo)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)

# your column names
my_vec <- c("headerA"," headerB", "headerC"," headerD", "headerE")

# remove whitespace
str_trim(my_vec, "both")

[1] "headerA" "headerB" "headerC" "headerD" "headerE"
```

Apply that to your data column names.

Comment: eddi actually had a more elegant solution above ( `setnames(foo, sub('^ *', '', names(foo)))` ), which would require less lines of code and no additional packages. But your answer works as well, so thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A years late answer, but share to those in need. Just add

```
fread(input,...,check.names=T)
```

This will check and correct all the column names so they can be indexed by $